# javascript for not doing a function

Tags: javascript, event-propagation

I have the following div structure:-

```
<div id="a" onclick="function1();">
<div id="b">
</div>

<div id="c">
</div>
</div>
```

Of course, clicking "a" will trigger function1() since "b" and "c" are located inside "a", when click on "b" or "c", function1() is also triggered.

Actually, I don't want function1() to be triggered when clicking "b". I tried to use z-index to make "b" very above "a", but it doesn't help.

I am seeking a way that is similar to:-

```
 <div id="b" onclick="function1() return false"></div>
```

Comment: Check [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target)?

Comment: you can use event.stopPropagation() on b and c click event function to prevent calling function1().

Comment: @Mohit Pandey: that was my solution indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look at the event's target.

With your HTML:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">Hello</div>
  <div class="c">World</div>
</div>
```

You can use this Javascript (jQuery):

```
$('.a').on('click', function(event){
  var $target = $(event.target);
  if($target.is('.a')){
    alert('You actually clicked .a');
  } else {
    alert('You did not click .a');
  }
});
```

Here's a quick demo with jQuery.

http://jsbin.com/ijinuz/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
$('#a').children().on('click', function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here you have a demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgJjc/4/).

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do this by passing `event` in the function set to `onclick`, and checking if the `event.target.id !== "b"`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>asdf</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "a" onclick = "doSomething(event);">
            div "a"
            <div id = "b">
                div "b"
            </div>
            <div id = "c">
                div "c"
            </div>
        </div>


        <script type = "text/javascript">
            function doSomething(e) {
                            if (e.target.id !== "b") {
                                alert(e.target.id);
                            }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icampbell2/bxJ4R/2/).